# LinkedList Spliterator without using size() method

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, spliterator

Given a `LinkedList`, which I want to split via `Spliterator`. I cannot use method `size()`. I have to implement `trySplit()` method with following condition: if `Spliterator` has at least 5 elements, return `new Spliterator`, which will go through first 4 elements; else `return null`. I don't get how to split it with following condition. Now I can get only one batch of elements. how can I get all batches? I'm struggling with this task more than 5 hours with no luck. Thank you in advance!

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html provides information how to use `Spliterator`, when the `size()` is known/allowed.

Interface:

```
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public interface Li<A> {
  Spliterator<A> getSpliterator();

  default Stream<A> stream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(getSpliterator(), false);
  }

  default Stream<A> parallelStream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(getSpliterator(), true);
  }
}
```

Class:

```
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class LL<A> implements Li<A>{
  private A hd;
  private LL<A> tl;

  public boolean isEmpty(){
    return hd == null && tl == null;
  }

  public void add(A a){
    if (isEmpty()){
      tl = new LL<>();
      hd = a;
    }else{
      tl.add(a);
    }
  }

  public LL(A hd, LL<A> tl){
    this.hd = hd;
    this.tl = tl;
  }

  public LL() {
    this(null, null);
  }

  public A get(int i) {
    return i==0 ? hd : tl.get(i-1);
  }

  @Override
  public Spliterator<A> getSpliterator(){
    return new MySplitter(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,this);
  }

  private class MySplitter implements Spliterator<A>{
    private LL<A> ll;
    int start;
    int end;

    MySplitter(int start, int end, LL<A> ll){
      this.ll = ll;
      this.start = start;
      this.end = end;
    }

    public A get(int i){
      return i==0 ? hd : tl.get(i-1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super A> action){
      if (this.get(start) != null && start < end) {
        action.accept(ll.get(start++));
        return true;
      }else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<A> trySplit(){
      try {
        ll.get(start + 5);
        end = start + 5;
      }catch (Exception e){
        return null;
      }
      start = end;
      end += 5;
      return new MySplitter(start, start + 4, ll).trySplit();
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize(){
      return Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics(){
      return ORDERED | SUBSIZED;
    }
  }
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
  LL<String> l = new LL();
  l.add("1");
  l.add("2");
  l.add("3");
  l.add("4");
  l.add("5");
  l.add("6");
  l.add("7");
  l.add("8");
  l.add("9");
  l.add("10");
  l.add("11");
  l.add("12");
  l.add("13");

  l.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("now parallel");
  System.out.println();
  l.parallelStream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13

now parallel

5
6
7
8
1
2
3
4
13
9
10
11
12
```

Actual output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13

now parallel

6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Usually each item in linked lists has a `next` method or variable which is a reference to the next item in the list or null if there is no more item in the list. you should navigate in a loop through this `next` method and count the number of items with a counter, this way you can find first four items easily.

Comment: @WIZARD thank you for the message. I can get every element with `get()` method. The problem is, that I can't get it working parallel with my conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved this problem. The main point on the way to the solution is the thing, that `trySplit()` method was wrong implemented. Firstly I have to check if the first five elements in `LL` are present. Then I am creating a new `LL<>();` and populate it with the first four elements from given list. Then I am changing the reference of the head `hd = tl.tl.tl.tl.hd;` and tail `tl = tl.tl.tl.tl.tl;`. After that I am returning a `new MySplitter(temp.hd, temp.tl);` object. The fixed working `LL` class is below:

```
public class LL<A> implements Li<A>{
  private A hd;
  private LL<A> tl;

  private boolean isEmpty(){
    return hd == null && tl == null;
  }

  public void add(A a){
    if (isEmpty()){
      tl = new LL<>();
      hd = a;
    }else{
      tl.add(a);
    }
  }

  private LL(A hd, LL<A> tl){
    this.hd = hd;
    this.tl = tl;
  }

  private LL() {
    this(null, null);
  }

  @Override
  public Spliterator<A> getSpliterator(){
    return new MySplitter(hd, tl);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    LL<String> l = new LL();
    l.add("1");
    l.add("2");
    l.add("3");
    l.add("4");
    l.add("5");
    l.add("6");
    l.add("7");
    l.add("8");
    l.add("9");
    l.add("10");
    l.add("11");
    l.add("12");
    l.add("13");

    l.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("now parallel");
    System.out.println();
    l.parallelStream().forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  private class MySplitter implements Spliterator<A> {
    private LL<A> tl;
    private A hd;

    MySplitter(A hd, LL<A> tl){
      this.tl = tl;
      this.hd = hd;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super A> action){
      if (hd != null) {
        action.accept(hd);
        hd = tl.hd;
        tl = tl.tl;
        return true;
      }else {
        return false;
      }
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<A> trySplit(){
      if(hd != null && tl.hd != null && tl.tl.hd != null && tl.tl.tl.hd != null
          && tl.tl.tl.tl.hd != null && tl.tl.tl.tl.tl.hd != null){
        LL<A> temp = new LL<>();
        temp.add(hd);
        temp.add(tl.hd);
        temp.add(tl.tl.hd);
        temp.add(tl.tl.tl.hd);
        hd = tl.tl.tl.tl.hd;
        tl = tl.tl.tl.tl.tl;
        return new MySplitter(temp.hd, temp.tl);
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize(){
      return Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics(){
      return ORDERED;
    }
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13

now parallel

5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Note that `trySplit()` is not required to return a spliterator of the same type. So you could store the five elements into a simpler data structure, e.g. array or `ArrayList` and return a spliterator for that, which will make further sub-splitting much more efficient. That’s similar to how `AbstractSpliterator` does it, which will return an array based spliterator, except that it will buffer up to 1024 elements on the first split, when having an unknown size.

Comment: Thank you very much for feedback! Your suggestion looks very good.